# Can I force pprint to print a set number of elements per line instead of width?

Tags: python-3.x, pprint

I have a list of of values and would like to print it in such a way that after a certain number of elements `pprint` forces a new line. I'm working with a dynamic data set and it's not possible to predict what the width of each new desired line will be. The elements themselves are exclusively strings and represent a boolean value. This is the desired effect:

```
[ o x x x o
  x o x x x
  x x o x o
  x o x o x 
  x x x x o ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) for that. The specifics will depend on your code & what you want but here's an example:

```
import random
import textwrap

some_booleans = [
    random.choice([True, False]) for _ in range(30)
]

stringified = ''.join('x' if elem else 'o' for elem in some_booleans)
adjusted_lines = textwrap.wrap(stringified, width=10)
to_print = '\n'.join(adjusted_lines)

print(to_print)
```

Output:

```
oxoxoxoxxo
xxxxooxooo
xxxxoxxxoo
```

Comment: Using numpy arrays has simplified this.